# Page not found with "empty slug" pattern on Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

In my application, I want to show a list of items based on certain url. For example, when I type mysite.com/restaurants/chinese/, I want to show all the Chinese restaurants. If I type mysite.com/restaurants/american/, I want to show all the American restaurants and so on. But when I type mysite.com/restaurants/ I want to show all the restaurants, so I wrote this code:

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^restaurants/', include('restaurants.urls')),
]
```

restaurants/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.views.generic import ListView

from .views import RestaurantLocationListView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$', RestaurantLocationListView.as_view()),
]
```

restaurants/views.py

```
from django.db.models import Q
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView

from .models import RestaurantLocation

class RestaurantLocationListView(ListView):
    def get_queryset(self):
        slug = self.kwargs.get('slug')

        if slug:
            queryset = RestaurantLocation.objects.filter(
                Q(category__iexact=slug) | Q(category__icontains=slug)
            )
        else:
            queryset = RestaurantLocation.objects.all()

        return queryset
```

It's everything working well, except when I put only mysite.com/restaurants/. This gives me an 404 error instead the list of all restaurants and I don't know why. Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like a url issue. In your restaraunts/url.py you need to add a url for it.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', RestaurantLocationListView.as_view()), # add it before
    url(r'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$', RestaurantLocationListView.as_view()),
]
```

Comment: It worked, thanks. But do you know why this is happening?

Comment: @flpn `mysite.com/restaurants/` doesn't match `'^(?P<slug>\w+)/$'` because there's a mandatory `w+`.